# How to add axis to balloonplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have the following plot

```
library(ggpubr)
dframe <- as.data.frame(Titanic)
head(dframe)
ggballoonplot(
  dframe, x = "Class", y = "Sex",
  size = "Freq", fill = "Freq",
  facet.by = c("Survived", "Age"),
  ggtheme = theme_bw()
)
```

[image]

[image]
I was wondering how to add a global x axis - for example "Survival rate"? and "Gender" to the y axis (as presented in the "sketch" of the lower figure

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The data you are displaying has "Class" on the x axis. If you just stuck an x axis with "survival rate" on it, what would it be referring to? Can you perhaps show a sketch of what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plot is pretty easy to make just using the regular `ggplot2`. I've never used `ggballoonplot`, so I'm not sure if you have a specific use case in mind.

```r
library(tidyverse)


dframe <- as.data.frame(Titanic)

dframe |>
  ggplot(aes(Class, Sex))+
  geom_point(aes(size = Freq, fill = Freq), pch = 21)+
  facet_grid(Survived~Age)+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x = "Survival Rate",
       y = "Gender")
```

[image]

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your code. However when I changed the first line to "ggplot(data=dframe, aes(Class, Sex))", it worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: that's because of the `|>` which is a pipe operator. You probably need to update your version of R.