# Merge ggplot fill and size legend keys

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

```
library(tidyverse)


dframe <- as.data.frame(Titanic)

dframe |>
  ggplot(aes(Class, Sex))+
  geom_point(aes(size = Freq, fill = Freq), pch = 21)+
  facet_grid(Survived~Age)+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x = "Survival Rate",
       y = "Gender")
```

How to update the legend to something like this:
[image]Following this post: [How to add axis to balloonplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73928917/how-to-add-axis-to-balloonplot)

In words: remove the lower legend and "fill" the upper one with color

Comment: does it help?:
`+ theme(legend.position = "right") + guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 6)))
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way with using `guides` and `guide_legend`.

```r
library(ggplot2)


dframe |>
  ggplot(aes(Class, Sex))+
  geom_point(aes(size = Freq, fill = Freq), pch = 21)+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE, override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))+
  guides(size = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))+
  facet_grid(Survived~Age)+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x = "Survival Rate",
       y = "Gender")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>