# Add additional facet to ggplot with conditional fill aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Following this question: [Merge ggplot fill and size legend keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74062090/merge-ggplot-fill-and-size-legend-keys)

I have this data, which produce the following plot:

```
library(tidyverse)
dframe <- as.data.frame(Titanic)
dframe$First<-ifelse(dframe$Class=="1st",1,0)

dframe %>%
  ggplot(aes(Class, Sex))+
  geom_point(aes(size = Freq, fill = Freq), pch = 21)+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE, override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))+
  guides(size = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))+
  facet_grid(Survived~Age)+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x = "Survival Rate",
       y = "Gender")
```

[image]

Now, let's assume that I want to adjust the fill of certain variables - e.g., all the first children:

```
dframe$First<-ifelse(dframe$Class=="1st",1,0)
```

[image]

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to map `shape` to the `First` variable, so that 1st class circles are represented by the empty circle shape (pch 1).

```
dframe %>%
    ggplot(aes(Class, Sex))+
    geom_point(aes(size = Freq, fill = Freq, shape = !First))+
    guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE, override.aes = list(shape = 21)))+
    guides(size = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))+
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 21))+
    facet_grid(Survived~Age)+
    theme_bw()+
    labs(x = "Survival Rate",
         y = "Gender")
```

[image]

You''l probably want to tweak the shape legend, or suppress altogether.

Comment: Yes, thanks! And how do I suppress it?

Comment: `guides(shape = FALSE)`, and you can also combine all your `guide()` calls into one

Answer (score 2):

You can just layer a new set of points on top. Just filter only the data you want to add.

```r
library(tidyverse)


dframe <- as.data.frame(Titanic)
dframe$First<-ifelse(dframe$Class=="1st",1,0)

dframe %>%
  ggplot(aes(Class, Sex))+
  geom_point(aes(size = Freq, fill = Freq), pch = 21)+
  geom_point(data = . %>% filter(Age == "Child" & Class == "1st"), 
             aes(color = "1st Class Children"), 
             pch = 22,
             size = 2,
             fill = "red")+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE, override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))+
  guides(size = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))+
  facet_grid(Survived~Age)+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x = "Survival Rate",
       y = "Gender",
       color = "")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or you can also leave the `size` parameter as freq and make the `colour` dependent on the "first class child" variable.

```
dframe$FirstClassChild<-ifelse(dframe$Class=="1st" & dframe$Age=="Child","yes","no")

dframe %>%
  ggplot(aes(Class, Sex))+
  geom_point(aes(size = Freq, colour = as.factor(FirstClassChild)))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE, override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))+
  guides(size = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))+
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = "First class children")) +
  facet_grid(Survived~Age)+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x = "Survival Rate",
       y = "Gender")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can use fill for both frequency and to indicate the status of passengers.
So this solution uses point size for frequency and fill for passenger status. The colour aesthetic is included as an equivalent to fill so that the circles and the legend is consistent and only displays once.

The values for variable `First` are converted into a factor as they are discrete.

```r
library(tidyverse)
dframe <- 
  as.data.frame(Titanic) |> 
  mutate(First = ifelse(Class=="1st" & Age == "Child", 1, 0),
         First = factor(First))

dframe %>%
  ggplot(aes(Class, Sex))+
  geom_point(aes(size = Freq, fill = First, colour = First), pch = 21)+
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c(1, 0),
                    labels = c("Children in first class", "All passengers except children in first class"),
                    values = c( "red", "green" ))+
  scale_colour_manual(breaks = c(1, 0),
                    labels = c("Children in first class", "All passengers except children in first class"),
                    values = c("red", "green"))+
  guides(size = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))+
  facet_grid(Survived~Age)+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x = "Survival Rate",
       y = "Gender",
       fill = "Passengers",
       colour = "Passengers")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>